# Difference between pure and thermal states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, density-operator, quantum-states

As far as I know by inserting a harmonic potential $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}m \omega x^2$ into the time-independent schrödinger equation I can obtain the wave-functions eigenstates and eigenvalues (energies).

So let us assume we have a quantum harmonic oscillator. Depending on the set-up this harm. osci. can be in a pure state $\mid \psi \rangle = \mid 0\rangle$ with density matrix $\rho = \mathrm{diag}\{1,0,0,..\}$ or in a thermal state with a density matrix $\tau(\beta) = \mathrm{diag}\{P_1,P_2,P_3,...\}$ where $P_1\leq P_2 \leq P_3 \leq ...$

So both **states** (pure vs. thermal) relate to the same Hamiltonian with the same eigenvalues it's just that the probability distribution is different. Is that correct?

Also I find it somewhat confusing when we are talking about 'states the system is in' vs. 'eigenstates of the Hamiltonian' which are 2 completely different things as far as I understand this. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian is a pure state, which is distinct from a mixed state. A thermal state is a mixed state.

Comment: Hm, when you say 'eigenstate of the Hamiltonian is a pure state' you mean not any specific pure state $\mid n \rangle$ but just that in general the property that any eigenstate of the Hamiltonian is a state that has only one 1 on the diagonal of the density matrix and rest is $0$, correct?

I.e. all these $\mid 0\rangle ,\mid 1\rangle , \mid 2\rangle ....$ are eigenstates of H.

Comment: All eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are pure states. But not all pure states are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. For example, $|n \rangle + |m \rangle$ is a pure state.

Comment: The form of the density matrix depends on the basis you're using. Yes, if you use the energy basis, then the density matrix of an energy eigenstate is mostly zeroes, with a single $1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions about the basics of quantum mechanics, and while you might get a few answers, this really won't be efficient. It would be much better to sit down for a few hours with a good book. Almost any book on quantum mechanics will cover _all_ of the questions you've asked.

Comment: Yes I'll do that, but I do get a more and more clear picture the more we discuss this. I'm also taking notes as we speak. 
The way I understood this now is that any system can be either in an eigenstate of its Hamiltonian (simpler case) or in a non-eigenstate state like the thermal state $\tau(\beta)$. At least in our case the non-eigenstate state $\tau(\beta)$ is always a mixture of the eigenstates (pure states), hence a mixed state.

Comment: Yes so a harmonic oscillator (system we are currently discussing) can be either in a pure state, which is an eigenstate of H, in a pure state, which is not eigenstate of H or in any mixed state which is not eigenstate of H.
An example for a mixed state the system can be in would be the thermal state. Is that correct?